# Lead conversion to Person Account automatic Record Type

Tags: apex, record-type

I created 4 record types, 2 on leads and 2 on account. The names of the record types are the same on leads and on account.

I want that when I convert a lead to a person account. The record type of the new Account to be set as A, if the record type of the Lead was A.

I don't want salesforce to let the salesforce user have the choice between A and B.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Per [Map Lead record type to Account record type](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385391&type=1), what you can do is create a formula field on Lead to get the record type, a custom field on the Account, with a field mapping between the two, and then use a Record-Triggered Flow (it suggests the use of the outdated Workflow Rule) in order to set the record type in Account based on the record type from the Lead.